# Intelligent branching in svn

Tags: svn, version-control

I wish to create a branch in SVN for a project but I wish to add only limited files into the Branch

like if I have 20 files and I changed 5 files for Branch. only those 5 files should be checked into branch. Eclipse should indirectly take rest of the files from trunk. would that be possible ?

and therefore until I switch back to trunk all the files that I commit should be in branch and rest of them in trunk only .. so that my workspace can include all the latest changes in trunk

Answer (score 0):

> create a branch in SVN for a project but I wish to add only limited files into the Branch

Impossible. Branch is **always full snapshot** of **some subtree** at **some moment**